# onTap(int i) event on ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> fires for only 1 item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mapview, android-maps, itemizedoverlay

I am using a MapView (google's) and add some overlays onto it.
I use my own overlay class which looks like this:

```
public class MyOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>
```

When I zoom out and cause all my items to be at the same location and tap the image, I get onTap event for only 1 out of all the items ehich are at the tapped location.

I want to be able to get onTap event for each and every item which is under the location on the map which I tap on, or either an ability to ask the map for all items at a specific rectangle where I press.

this is my code for debugging:

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int i)
{                
    super.onTap(i);
    return false;           
}
```

and get only 1 tap for each overlay.

Is it possible? how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is this: (Note that this is pseudo code)

```
   // Over ride the onTouchEvent
   @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, final MapView mapView) {
        final int action=event.getAction();
        final int x = (int)event.getX();
        final int y = (int)event.getY();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // get the zoom level 
        zoomLevel = mapView.getZoomLevel();

        if(zoomLevel > appropriateZoom)
        {
              if(items != null) {
                for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++){
                    OverlayItem item = items.get(i);
                    Point mp = new Point(0,0);
                    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(item.getPoint(), mp);
                    xDragTouchOffset=x-mp.x;
                    yDragTouchOffset=y-mp.y;
                    if (hitTest(item, marker, x-(mp.x-(xDragImageOffset+xDragTouchOffset*2)), y-(mp.y-((yDragImageOffset/2)+yDragTouchOffset)))) {
                   // This item has been tapped. Do what you want here. 
         }

        }
```

This is only a idea/hint to get you started.

Comment: isn't it possible to some how register to onTap of each and every OverlayItem? this will probably be better than starting to calculate zoom situations....

Comment: OverlayItem does not support onTap, but [Overlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html) does.